# How to pass const parameter in another js file

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, constructor

const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
how can i send (searchInput)s value  in another js file ?[image: There is , i creating const][image: and i want pass this value here in the term of query]

Some suggestion and Solution how can i write code or pass this parameter

Comment: Hey There the only way is to either have this located in your store state that can be available to access throughout your application or this is only achievable by parent to child props being passed down and up Hope this helps with some guidance

Comment: Please add code as code blocks not screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You may try pass from parrent to child components

```
//profile.js

const [serachInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

return(
<div> 
   <Searchnesseacary searchInput={searchInput} />
</div>
)

//Searchnesseacary.js
function Searchnesseacary({searhInput}){
  {!--code you want here--!}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

It will enable usage of objects as global variables that can be user across various js files.